# Sequential execution of Reactive tasks in reactor Java

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm working on converting a blocking sequential orchestration framework to reactive. Right now, these tasks are dynamic and are fed into the engine by a JSON input. The engine pulls classes and executes the `run()` method and saves the state with the responses from each task.
How do I achieve the same chaining in reactor? If this was a static DAG, I would have chained it with `flatMap` or `then` operators but since it is dynamic, How do I proceed with executing a reactive task and collecting the output from each task?

Examples:
Non reactive interface:

```
public interface OrchestrationTask {
 OrchestrationContext run(IngestionContext ctx);
}
```

Core Engine

```
public Status executeDAG(String id) {
  IngestionContext ctx = ContextBuilder.getCtx(id);
  List<OrchestrationTask> tasks = app.getEligibleTasks(id);

  for(OrchestrationTask task : tasks) {
    // Eligible tasks are executed sequentially and results are collected.
    OrchestrationContext stepContext = task.run(ctx);
    if(!evaluateResult(stepContext)) break;
  }
  return Status.SUCCESS;
}
```

Following the above example, if I convert tasks to return Mono<?> then, how do I wait or chain other tasks to operate on the result on previous tasks?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Update::

Reactive Task example.

```
public class SampleTask implements OrchestrationTask {  
  @Override
  public Mono<OrchestrationContext> run(OrchestrationContext context) {  
  // Im simulating a delay here. treat this as a long running task (web call) But the next task needs the response from the below call.
  return Mono.just(context).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
 }
```

So i will have a series of tasks that accomplish various things but the response from each task is dependent on the previous and is stored in the Orchestration Context. Anytime an error is occurred, the orchestration context flag will be set to false and the flux should stop.

Comment: Could you give an example of your blocking code at the mo? I can't quite picture how it works from your description.

Comment: @MichaelBerry updated the  post. Let me know if you still need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear - what here needs to become reactive? You mention task.run() returns a mono, but is that it - or will app.getEligibleTasks(), ContextBuilder.getCtx() and evaluateResult() also need to avoid blocking operations by returning a reactive publisher? Also, the method currently seems to *always* return `SUCCESS`, but will only execute `evaluateResult()` on each `StepContext` until one returns false. Is that the behaviour you'd need to emulate in a reactive implementation?

Comment: @michaelberry other methods do not have blocking operations. Only run returns Mono and it returns the status based on the tasks written in run.  The status success is for this method but it will stop executing next tasks if evaluateResult says false.

Comment: @MichaelBerry any idea?

Comment: Steady on there, I only have a certain amount of time to help out on SO! See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, we can:

- Create the flux from the task list (if it's appropriate to generate the task list reactively then you can replace that arraylist with the flux directly, if not then keep as-is);
- `flatMap()` each task to your `task.run()` method (which as per the question now returns a `Mono`;
- Ensure we only consume elements while `evaluateResult()` is true;
- ...then finally just return the `SUCCESS` status as before.

So putting all that together, just replace your loop & return statement with:

```
Flux.fromIterable(tasks)
        .flatMap(task -> task.run(ctx))
        .takeWhile(stepContext -> evaluateResult(stepContext))
        .then(Mono.just(Status.SUCCESS));
```

(Since we've made it reactive, your method will obviously need to return a `Mono<Status>` rather than just `Status` too.)

Update as per the comment - if you just want this to execute "one at a time" rather than with multiple concurrently, you can use `concatMap()` instead of `flatMap()`.

Comment: the generation of task list is merely collecting beans of a class type. I believe that should be fine correct?

Comment: @PavanKumar Yup, should be unless it's getting them through some weird blocking operation.

Comment: Also, the evaluateResult method when returned false, should terminate the flux and return the orchestration context until that point. Is there an elegant way that I can do it?

Comment: Tasks in the iterable have dependency on each other. Right now, these tasks are triggered in parallel and if there is an IO call ( Webclient for ex), the next task is executed before the response for previous task is returned. Any Idea on how we can make sure that each task gets executed one after the other? After getting the response that is.

Comment: @PavanKumar Can you update the question with the correct blocking code you're trying to emulate? Right now your code only ever returns `SUCCESS`, it just stops going through the list as soon as `task.run()` returns false. I've updated the answer with how to get the "one at a time" behaviour.

Comment: I updated the post. I see that passing concurrency value is helping. But can I use concatMap for the same usecase? What do you think?

Comment: @PavanKumar I'm having a slow day - you're correct, `concatMap()` is exactly the right operator to use for this usecase.